# Upgrading from AngularJS 1.5 to 1.7 throws "Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deep-copy

I would like to copy my controller.
I had the following code (invalid in angular 1.7):

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) {
            return;
        }

        // Do a copy of the controller
        scope.ctrlCopy = {};
        angular.copy(ctrl, scope.ctrlCopy); // <- fail here
```

This fails with:

> Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported

I tried `Object.copy` but I need a prototype function of the controller (`$setValidity`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
scope.ctrlCopy = Object.assign(Object.create(ctrl.__proto__), ctrl);
```

Where `Object.create(ctrl.__proto__)` is used to create prototype functions 
And [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign) to create the deep copy.

Comment: but Object.create(ctrl.__proto__) creates a new object with only the properties of the parent type, all the custom properties that ctrl has aren't copied